# How can I serialize a form in JavaScript asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am using some javascript to post my form but I dont want to have to submit each form field is there a way I can serlize this to an object in .net so that it will bring in all the form contents.

```
section Scripts {
    <script>
    function confirmEdit() {
            swal({
                title: "MIS",
                text: "Case Created your Case Number is " + $("#Id").val(),
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
            }).then((willUpdate) => {
                if (willUpdate) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/tests/edit/" + $("#Id").val(),
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            Id: $("#Id").val(),
                            Name: $("#Name").val()
                        },
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function () {
                            swal("Done!", "It was succesfully edited!", "success")
                                .then((success) => {
                                    window.location.href = "/tests/index"
                                });

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            swal("Error updating!", "Please try again", "error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `$('#FormID').serialize()`? https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

asp.net core will automatically bind json data using the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
data: {
   id: $("#Id").val(),
   name: $("#Name").val()
},
```

and then in your controller

```
[HttpPost("/tests/edit/")]
public IActionResult Process([FromBody] MyData data){ ... }
```

where `MyData` is

```
public class MyData
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: must I do each field I have 20, 30 fields in the form can i not serlise it some way at the data level

Comment: @rogue39nin instead of `MyData` try `Dictionary<string,string>`

Answer (score 0):

section Scripts {  function confirmEdit() {
swal({ title: "MIS", text: "Case Created your Case Number is " + $("#Id").val(), icon: "warning", buttons: true, dangerMode: true, }).then((willUpdate) => { if (willUpdate) {
var obj = { Id: $("#Id").val(), Name: $("#Name").val() }
$.ajax({ url: "/tests/edit/" + $("#Id").val(), type: "POST", data: JSON.Stringify(obj), dataType: "html", success: function () { swal("Done!", "It was succesfully edited!", "success") .then((success) => { window.location.href = "/tests/index" }); }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { swal("Error updating!", "Please try again", "error"); } }); } }); }  }

in c# use

public ActionResult FormPost(MyData obj)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following methods to submit the form data to action method:

1. using the [serialize() method](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the  controls within the form.

   ```
   @model MVCSample.Models.OrderViewModel

    <h4>OrderViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Showsummary" asp-controller="Home" method="post" class="signup-form">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="OrderId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="OrderId" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="OrderId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="OrderName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="OrderName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="OrderName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div id="packages">

                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Packages.Count; i++)
                    {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Packages[i].Pid" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Packages[i].Pid" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Packages[i].Pid" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <br />
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Packages[i].PackageTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Packages[i].PackageTitle" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Packages[i].PackageTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div> 
                    }

                </div> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="summary" value="Summary" />
        <div id="page_3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#summary").click(function () {
                console.log("calling summary");
                event.preventDefault();  
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/Showsummary",  //remember change the controller to your owns.
                    data: $("form.signup-form").serialize(), 
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data) 
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
   ```

Code the the action method:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Showsummary(OrderViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            //...
            return PartialView("OrderSummary", model);
        }
        catch
        {
            return PartialView("OrderSummary", model);
        }
    }
```

After clicking the button, the result like this:

[image]

As we can see that, we could get the element's value in the form and even the nested entity.

Note: Only "[successful controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

2. Create a JavaScript object, and post it to action method.

Change the JavaScript script as below:

```
$(function () {
    $("#summary").click(function () {
        console.log("calling summary");
        event.preventDefault();
        //create a object to store the entered value.
        var OrderViewModel = {};
        //using jquery to get the entered value.
        OrderViewModel.OrderId = $("input[name='OrderId']").val();
        OrderViewModel.OrderName = $("input[name='OrderName']").val();

        var packages = []; 
        //var count = $("#packages>.form-group").length; //you could use it to check the package count            
        $("#packages>.form-group").each(function (index, item) {
            var package = {}
            package.Pid = $(item).find("input[name='Packages[" + index + "].Pid']").val();
            package.PackageTitle = $(item).find("input[name='Packages[" + index + "].PackageTitle']").val();
            packages.push(package);
        });
        //add the nested entity
        OrderViewModel.Packages = packages;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Showsummary",  //remember change the controller to your owns.
            data: OrderViewModel,  
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                $('#page_3').html(data);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

By using the above code, I could also get the submit entity, you could refer to it.