# how to change quantity or update under the Foreach loop for cart checkout

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am making the Review Cart & Checkout form. IF the user wants to change the quantity I want that if quantity is changed the price of it will be changed automatically. But here I can not update the input quantity under for each loop.similarly can not change anything. how I fix this problem.
Here is my code.

```
        [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var hi = _db.Spray.Include(c => c.ProductTypes).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            ProductVm product = new ProductVm
            {
                Name = hi.Name,
                Id = hi.Id,
                Image=hi.Image,
                Image1=hi.Image1,
                Quantity = hi.Quantity,
                Price = hi.Price,
            };
           

            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(product);
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Details")]

        public async Task <IActionResult> ProductDetails(ProductVm pb)
        {

            List<Spray> sprays = new List<Spray>();

            //if (id == null)
            //{
            //    return NotFound();
            //}

            //var yes = _db.Spray.Include(c => c.ProductTypes).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);


            ProductVm product = new ProductVm()
            {
                Name = pb.Name,
                Id = pb.Id,
                Image = pb.Image,
                Image1=pb.Image1,
                Quantity = pb.Quantity,
                Price = pb.Price,
             
            };
          

            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            sprays = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Spray>>("sprays");
            if (sprays == null)
            {
                sprays = new List<Spray>();
            }
            sprays.Add(product);
            HttpContext.Session.Set("sprays", sprays);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Cart()
        {

            List<Spray> sprays = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Spray>>("sprays");
           
            
            if (sprays == null)
            {
                sprays = new List<Spray>();
            }
            return View(sprays);
        }
```

```
@model List<Spray>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cart";
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">

        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity Update</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/@item.Image" width="200px" height="150px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>@item.Name</td>

                        <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                        <td>@item.Price</td>
                        @*<td> <input type="number" asp-for="@item.Quantity" min="0" max="1000" /></td>*@
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" asp-for="@item.Quantity" min="0" max="1000"  />
                        </td>

                        <td>@(item.Price * item.Quantity)</td>






                        @*<td>@item.ProductTypes.ProductName</td>*@
                        <td>@item.ProductColor</td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-area="Customer" asp-action="Remove" asp-controller="LaptopShow" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>



                }
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div>
            <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="SprayShow" class="btn btn-primary">Back To Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-right">
            <h3>Total Amount</h3>
            <h3>Grand Total : @Model.Sum(c => c.Price * c.Quantity)</h3>
            <a asp-area="Customer" asp-action="Checkout" asp-controller="Order2" class="btn btn-info">Process To CheckOut</a>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<h1>This is free trial</h1>

<script src="./src/bootstrap-input-spinner.js"></script>
<script>
    $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner()
</script>
```

here is my output

I am beginner, Please anyone help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach an JQuery change event for the Quantity Update input control, then, when you change the quantity value, in its change event, you could get the new quantity value and update the Total.

Sample code as below:

```
    [HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        ProductVm product = new ProductVm()
        {
            Name = "Wild black Stone",
            Id = 1001,
            Image = "images/Image1.jpg", 
            Quantity = 2,
            Price = 68.00, 
        };
        ProductVm product2 = new ProductVm()
        {
            Name = "Wild red Stone",
            Id = 1002,
            Image = "images/Image1.jpg",
            Quantity = 3,
            Price = 58.00,
        };
        List<ProductVm> vmlist = new List<ProductVm>();
        vmlist.Add(product);
        vmlist.Add(product2);
        return View(vmlist);
    }
```

Code in the View:

```
@model List<MVCSample.Models.ProductVm>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
 
<div> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6"> 
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity Update</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead> 
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="~/@item.Image" width="200px" height="150px" />
                            </td>
                            <td>@item.Name</td>

                            <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                            <td>@item.Price</td> 
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" asp-for="@item.Quantity" min="0" max="1000" />
                            </td>

                            <td>@(item.Price * item.Quantity)</td> 
                            <td>
                                <a asp-area="Customer" asp-action="Remove" asp-controller="LaptopShow" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>  
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>


        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="SprayShow" class="btn btn-primary">Back To Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right">
                <h3>Total Amount</h3>
                <h3>Grand Total : @Model.Sum(c => c.Price * c.Quantity)</h3>
                <a asp-area="Customer" asp-action="Checkout" asp-controller="Order2" class="btn btn-info">Process To CheckOut</a>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function () {
         $("input[name='item.Quantity']").change(function () {
             //get the new quantity
             var newquantity = parseInt($(this).val());
             //update the original quantity value
             $(this).closest("tr").find("td")[2].innerHTML = newquantity;

             //get the price
             var price = parseFloat($(this).closest("tr").find("td")[3].innerHTML);
             //calculate the total
             $(this).closest("tr").find("td")[5].innerHTML = newquantity * price;


             //calcule the Grand Total
             var grandtotal = 0;
             $("tbody").find("tr").each(function (index, item) {
                 var value = parseFloat($(item).find("td")[5].innerHTML);
                 grandtotal += value;
             });
             $(".text-right h3:last").html("Grand Total : " + grandtotal.toString());
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Note: In the above sample code, I'm finding the element by the index (Zero based), Please check the columns number and change it based on your table.

Then, the screenshot as below:

[image]

Finally, when click the "Process To CheckOut" button, you could also use JQuery method to loop through the table and find the related value, then use Ajax method to submit the data to the action method (You could check my reply in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813695/how-can-i-serialize-a-form-in-javascript-asp-net) and use the second method to submit the data).

Comment: if I wanted to use +- button input spinner for increase or decrease quantity, so for that what jquery code I will use for.

Comment: @Pritomsarkar You could use [Font Awesome Icons](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/): [minus icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/minus) and [plus icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/plus) (need to add a span or div outside the icon), then, attach click event for them. In the Click event, you could get the input value and increase or decrease quantity, sample code [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/v1nsgbm5/).